Puzzle book with beautiful illustrations aimed at teenagers, the theme was similar to star wars space pilots racing against all odds to a destination

You were a fighter pilot in a division or army. Each space fighter had a number on it.
All the fighter space craft were from an alliance or something, and had a different color.
The puzzles were math based? Or required you looking at the book carefully.
Eventually your squadron would get picked off one by one slowly. Until you and only a few were left by the end.
The mission was so secret that you had to input the code you got on the rest of the pages in order to solve the final puzzle.
No one knew the code you just had to  make it to the end and the final page end there were faces shooting lasers or something at you.
Book was available in canada.

There was relatively few pages around 10-30 pages and the text wasn't the focus but the pictures and the solving puzzles

I vaguely remember this book or one like it (UK, 1980s or possibly early 1990s) - the spaceships slowly dropping out one by one, short book, just about all pictures.  Would love to see it again!

Same, rest in peace those brave souls
